# Boost Filesystem without the library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

Boost.Filesystem has a compiled library, unlike most components of Boost. How much of Boost.Filesystem is usable without linking to the library? That is, how much of it can be used in a header-only distro of Boost? Is it possible to use `filesystem::path`, just the class, without the global functions that access filesystem stuff?

Comment: It seems most of the things in path.hpp are header only. It's the operations that seem to be compiled.